# Migrate inheritance to database in different tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've made this structure in my models:

[image]

And I'll update my database like show below:

[image]

But if I add a migration and I update my database, I become this:

[image]

How could I migrate my classes to the database structure I will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table below is correct because the field `Discriminator` is a `nvarchar` variable that decided if the object is a topic, blog or comment. The fields `upvote` and `downvote` will be `null` if the topic is a comment, otherwise it will be not `null`.

[image]

In other words, it is not necessary to split the tables in your database. If I look to your class diagram I don't see any many to many relation.